# Read the `Power Saving Modes` settings on the MIUI devices

Tags: android, foreground-service, location-provider, battery-saver, miui

The `Power Saving Modes` settings is different from the regular Android OS Power Saver setting and accessible on MIUI devices only (or rather accessible at least on MIUI devices)

Settings -> Battery & Performance -> Manage apps battery usage

[image: Manage apps battery usage]

[image: Power Saving Modes]

The issue is that on MIUI devices this option is enabled by default and foreground service with location tracking enabled to continue to work when the app is backgrounded but new locations from GPS provider are not coming.

I want to read the mode setting to provide a user with UX which allows him to be aware that this option is enabled and consider it before backgrounding the app.

Is it possible to read this setting programmatically?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MIUI, but in vanilla Android you can accomplish that with ((PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).isPowerSaveMode();

Comment: in my case I need MIUI settings only, Android settings are fine and out of the scope of this question.